# can i load rootview's xib View to another class

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

can i load rootview's xib View to another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
```